# Repeatedly writing in same Excel file with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Java Apache poi library. I have to write data in an Excel file in chunks. It is my application scope that I can not write whole data at once to my Excel file so a batch size is fixed and writing data in batches (chunks). I am using following code.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet");
int rowNum = startIndex;

Row excelRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
int colNum = 1;

// Placing matrix results in rest of rows. Also keywrods in first column.
for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < keywords.size(); rowIndex++) {
    excelRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
    colNum = 0;
    Cell cell = excelRow.createCell(colNum);
    cell.setCellValue(keywords.get(rowIndex));

    colNum++;
    for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < scoreResults[rowIndex].length; colIndex++) {
        cell = excelRow.createCell(colNum);
        cell.setCellValue(scoreResults[rowIndex][colIndex]);
        colNum++;
    }
}

FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputExcelFileName,true);
workbook.write(outputStream);

outputStream.close();
workbook.close();
```

This is written in a function and I have to call that function again and again. If my elements size is same of my batch size then there is no issue. File is created and opened successfully. Problem comes when let say batch size is 10 and my elements are 15. Then 2nd iteration is not happening successfully. Not any getting any error at run time but when I open excel file then MS(2010) report this error:

```
Excel found unreadable content in 'file_name'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?
```

If I click on "yes" then it recovers contents of first iteration only. If batch size is 10 then only 10 elements will be recovered. So, issue exist after 1st iteration.

I have spent a lot of time in figuring out this issue but still unable to resolve it. If someone can help I will be thankful to you.

Comment: what kind of data do you write into the workbook? do you use `XSSF` for a `.xls` file?

Comment: I have to write string and double values. Using "xlsx" as file format.

Comment: This code generates a single-sheet excel spreadsheet with rows equal to the number of keywords and columns equal to scoreResults[rowIndex].length + 1.  There is no mention of batch size in this code nor any indicator that batch size would have any impact whatsoever on the output here.  Could you please provide the additional code necessary to show how batch size fits in here?

Comment: I guess keeping workbook object alive till the whole processing is done and writing into the file at the end should help.

Comment: I assume, you write the excel file, open it in Excel, close it and try to append new data to the existing file?

Comment: `FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputExcelFileName,true); workbook.write(outputStream);`: This is not possible. A `XSSFWorkbook` is nothing those bytes simply can be written appended to an existing Excel workbbook file. The `XSSFWorkbook` is a `ZIP` archive containing the workbook data in a directory structure having `XML` files in it. It only can be written as whole unit into an file.

Comment: @KDM your suggestion works well when batch size is small. Now Excel file is opened successfully. But in real time I have to make batch size high like 1000. At these high values now I am getting GCOverheadLimitExceed exception.

Comment: @IQV I am writing data to file. Closing it. Then calling these 2 steps again.

Comment: @AxelRichter While writing as whole I am getting GCOverheadLimitExceed Exception. Which means 98% of CPU time is busy in freeing less than 2% of heap memory. To avoid this I went with batch technique and I thought to write data of fixed batch size and close file and do repeat steps. But that did not work out so I post this question.

Comment: As @AxelRichter mentioned you can't append data to an excel file. You have to read the entire existing data, append the new data and wrote all back in the file.

Comment: In that case is there anything that I can improve in this code to avoid from GCOverheadLimitExceed Exception?

Comment: OR if there is any other java lib which can fulfill my purpose?

Comment: If it is a table you are creating, it might be easier to create a CSV file and then convert into XSL. I am sure POI will have a way of doing that.